# Gatsby.js: Preprocessing Relative Path Links in Markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby, contentful

I'm wondering if there's a way, possibly by creating a plugin for `gatsby-transformer-remark`, that relative-path links could be converted to act as if they were using `<Link>` from `gatsby-link`.

For instance, say I have the following in a markdown file:

```
# Here is a Header

Check out my about page:

[About](/about)
```

If I import this markdown and display it with:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: whatever.childMarkdownRemark.html }} />
```

Then when the "About" link is clicked it breaks the single-page app magic.

Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a plugin for this called [gatsby-plugin-catch-links](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-catch-links/).

Install it:

```
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-catch-links
```

Add it in your **gatsby-config.js** file:

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-catch-links`];
```

You can find a very nice documentation on how to use remark with Gatsby at https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/

For your question, I found [this article here](https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/copy-linked-files-intercepting-local-links/#intercepting-local-links).

Comment: Welp, that was easy, thanks! I'll award the bounty tomorrow (stack overflow requires a min of 1 day).

Comment: mine didn't work. `[link](/some-link)` still reloading / open new tab

Comment: What if my internal links are links to other .md files? Like [About](/about.md).

Comment: @gpbl You can link them with `[my link should be called this](../relative_path_to_md_file_from_current_file)`. You would have to remove the `.md` at the end though